# Architecture design for Linux administrative interface

Tags: design, design-patterns, c, linux

I've developed an IoT device utilising OpenWrt so my design needs run a on a shoe-string budget of resources.

I need to be able to push small amounts of data, up to 300bytes to my app on a very irregular basis, something once a week and other time maybe 10 times a day, so I'm not looking to over-engineer this thing, but I do want it to be well engineered. I don't run a web server, app server nor java on the device and everything else is coded 99% in ANSI C.

Now I need to develop a mobile app to push these 300bytes to the IoT device and I'm procrastinating on the design. I'm interested in others'opinions on how best to proceed. I've considered a daemon that listens on a UDP port for a basic bytestream with a checksum, but I worry about security even though the IoT device sits on an Intranet. If I add TLS that's a lot of work for very little use. I could utilise sftp/scp but then I need to run the applicable processes on the device, which breaks with my minimalist design approach.

The 300bytes being sent just need to be appended to the end of a file on the device.

It seems I'm getting caught up in my head so I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If your device can run OpenWRT it's many orders of magnitude more powerful than most IoT devices. You can use something like an Arduino or less powerful device to do this. I know for a fact that such a device can:

- Use UDP or TCP.
- Communicate using very well established cryptographic protocols considered to be secure for decades using a **shared key** unique per device (the key is loaded at the factory or in-house).
- Perform **reliable* firmware upgrades** and downgrades between any two versions you want to run.
- Send and receive many kilobytes per day **for many years on a watch battery.**

Running such a slim device actually gives you a lot of advantages:

- A single person can actually understand *all* the software running on it. As soon as you're running Linux there is not a chance that you will ever have the time to read all the code and understand it.
- You can tailor the communications protocol very easily. I've mostly worked with interchange languages like JSON and XML, but a very well-defined custom package format right on top of TCP is fantastic for debugging. Your communications stack is basically two or three levels shallower than most microservice architectures.
- Since the only thing running on your device is so simple you actually have a chance to **test it exhaustively.** This should start on day 1, and if you follow it through you'll have a rock solid service.

* *Atomic* in the sense that only a single bit flip is responsible for deciding which stored firmware is running, *reentrant* as in resuming firmware upload at the exact package it last sent, *secure* because the entire transfer is encrypted like any other traffic, and *safe* because a checksum is verified before flipping to the new firmware.